# Why does my ng-if work properly only after a refresh?

Tags: angularjs

A `ng-if` inside a ng-template (.aspx file) never works when the page is first loaded.

After a refresh, it will behave as expected. My guess is that it isn't being evaluated until after the elements are created.

How do I ensure it is being handled last to ensure it behaves properly?

```
<a ng-if='node.wrappedObject.isUserAdded'
   class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs userAddedRemoveTermButton" 
   data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: It would help to see relevant code for the implementation. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See new code snippet

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: I am aware. It is not my code to share. Just looking for general nuances of ng-if and if anyone has seen this problem where it only works after refresh.

Comment: If you want to know the nuances of `ng-if`, read [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). The `ng-if` directive adds an inherited scope which may be fighting the other things on the element.

Comment: Add `{{ node.wrappedObject.isUserAdded }}` somewhere (at the same level as your `<a>`. See what that shows up as at the level of your `ng-if`. Does it have a boolean value? How does the value get set?

Comment: Thank you, Brian! I found where isUserAdded was set and set it to false by default. All is well now.